# Convert 1345 to 1.3k and so on

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to change anything above 1000 into 1 decimal place.

So e.g. 900 stays as 900, but 1345 becomes 1.3 and then I'll add the trailing K.

It's never going to become millions, so i don't have to be worrying about checking for the trailing letter.

But I am not sure how to add a decimal place?

Comment: If `$val` is more than 1000, divide by 1000 and use `round($val, 1)` to convert it to one decimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a class to encapsulate this logic:

```
interface Quantifier {
    public function quantify($input);
}

class NumberQuantifier implements Quantifier {
    protected $quantifierList;

    public function __construct($quantifierList) {
        $this->quantifierList = $quantifierList;
        arsort($this->quantifierList); //Make sure they are largest too smallest.
    }

    public function quantify($number) {
        foreach ($this->quantifierList as $symbol => $threshold) {
            if ($threshold > $number) continue;

            return number_format($number / $threshold, 1) . $symbol;
        }
    }
}
```

When creating an instance of this class, you can pass it a list of your quantifiers:

```
$numberQuantifier = new NumberQuantifier(array(
    'B' => 1000000000,
    'M' => 1000000,
    'K' => 1000
));
```

You can then use it like this:

```
echo $numberQuantifier->quantify(148293);
echo $numberQuantifier->quantify(2356458);
echo $numberQuantifier->quantify(23568534);
echo $numberQuantifier->quantify(8927492842);
```

Outputs (added line breaks):

```
148.3K
2.4M
23.6M
8.9B
```

[See it here](http://ideone.com/6CeNz6)

---

Now, imagine you want to quantify something other than just a number. Here are some examples:

#### File size

```
$fileSizeQuantifier = new NumberQuantifier(array(
    'TB' => 1099511627776,
    'GB' => 1073741824,
    'MB' => 1048576,
    'KB' => 1024
));
```

#### Mass

Consider an example where you might want more than a single quantifier type:

```
$metricMassQuantifier = new NumberQuantifier(array(
    'Mg'  => 1000000,    //megagram
    'kg'  => 1000,       //kilogram
    'hg'  => 100,        //hectogram
    'dag' => 10,         //decagram
    'g'   => 1,          //gram
    'dg'  => 1/10,       //decigram
    'cg'  => 1/100,      //centigram
    'mg'  => 1/1000,     //millgram
    'mcg' => 1/10000000  //microgram
));

$imperialMassQuantifier = new NumberQuantifier(array(
    'gr'  => 1/7000, //grain
    'dr'  => 1/256,  //drachm
    'oz'  => 1/16,   //ounce
    'lb'  => 1,      //pound
    'st'  => 14,     //stone
    'qtr' => 28,     //quarter
    'cwt' => 112,    //hundredweight
    't'   => 2240    //ton
));

echo "Metric: {$metricMassQuantifier->quantify(456)} \r\n";
echo "Imperial: {$imperialMassQuantifier->quantify(456)} \r\n";
```

Output

```
Metric: 4.6hg 
Imperial: 4.1cwt
```

[See this demo](http://ideone.com/asE5fQ)

Comment: I added a sort to the constructor so that the order of your input list doesn't matter.

Comment: If your class contains one method and no state, then it shouldn't be a class; it should be a function.  Aside from that, I don't see much use in configurable quantifiers.  When would they change?

Comment: @drrcknlsn It depends on what you are quantifying. What if he wants to quantify bandwidth speed? What if he wants to quantify time? weight? length? What if he wants to quantify the phases of the moon? What if he wants multiple types of quantifiers in the same request? What if he wants to change the symbols of the quantifiers? There are lots of classes that provide only a single method. This should probably implement a common interface, in reality. Also, it has state; the quantifier list. No, a function here would not be cleaner.

Comment: @crush The quantifier list is not really state here; it's artificial state.  It's only state because you made it so.  It can't change, and it's just a static dependency for the `quantify()` method.  As written, this should merely be a function with 2 parameters - number and quantifiers.  Good point on quantifying things other than normal numbers, though.

Comment: @drrcknlsn If you want to nitpick, it wouldn't be hard to add a method to add new quantifiers on the fly.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Why keep passing the quantifier list around every time, instead of stashing it in an instance of the object that will always use it? See the example above for metric and imperial units in same request.

Comment: @crush There is still no mutable state, so a class is not the right tool for the job.  It's a single operation with inputs that produce an output (the very *definition* of function).  For your example with multiple units, I would point you in the direction of `quantifyMetric(456); quantifyImperial(456);`, with an optional parameter to override the default quantifiers, if that's desirable.

Comment: @drrcknlsn What if someone wanted to implement a Quantifier that did have a mutable state? Not that classes must have a mutable state, but whatever. Passing a custom list around to every function call isn't my idea of clean code. Copying and pasting a function, changing its name, just to make a new quantifier isn't anywhere near clean. You're welcome to your own opinion, of course.

Comment: @crush There's a reason we have `explode(<delim>, <string>);` and not `ArrayCreator::__construct(<delim>); ArrayCreator::explode(<string>);`.  Single operations with no mutable state don't belong in classes.  They can be *methods* in classes, if their behavior operates on some shared state (e.g. `String.split(<delim>)`), but they don't warrant dedicated classes.  Anyway, just trying to help.  :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn If you want to debate when something can be a class or not, you might want to head over to http://programmers.stackexchange.com and try to convince them that something should only be a class if it has mutable state. I doubt you will find many proponents. Furthermore, I thought I made it quite clear that it would not be inconceivable that someone might implement the Quantifier interface with a class that has some mutable state. I've more than sufficiently demonstrated why a class could be desired here. I wish you the best of luck with your anti-class rhetoric going forward.

Comment: @drrcknlsn You also might want to rethink your `String` example, considering `String` in most languages is immutable. It's not shared state. It's immutable state.

Comment: @crush It's not the immutability of the state that makes a class the wrong choice here; it's the combination of immutable state and being *a single operation*.  Were it to have many operations that shared the same state, or it actually managed state rather than just being a container for it, or you wanted to make use of polymorphism, use this as part of a strategy pattern, or any of a million good enough reasons for it to be a class, then I would support it.  But making it a class *just in case* someday it might need to be is over-engineering.  As much as I hate YAGNI, it's relevant here.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I feel like you must be trying to bait me into slinging insults by continuously missing the point, failing to comprehend a more advanced use case where polymorphism would be appropriate, and spewing misinformation about what constitutes a class vs a series of functions. Listen, if you and your developers want to run around making functions that point to functions that point to functions all in the name of avoiding encapsulation, be my guest. That doesn't make it the right choice. Your argument that classes must have more than a single operation is ludicrous and ignorant. I'm done.

Comment: @crush I'm sorry that you seem to take criticism as a personal affront, as it's certainly not the intention.  I'll leave you with one last thing to consider, which is that there is a very good reason why the functional answer received 5x the upvotes of your own, and it's not because I get 4 votes.  :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn It received 3 votes before I ever posted my answer. Consider that. Sure, that answer works fine if your intent is to only ever convert a number into `K`. You're advocating creating heaps of utility functions that all do basically the same thing. Criticism is one thing. But you are bordering on stupidity in your argument at this point. Also, I had 2 upvotes until you downvoted me just now to try and make a point. It's clear now that your purpose is to try and defame my answer in some lame attempt to sound correct. Cheers mate!

Comment: @crush I downvoted you because I had been reserving my vote until after hearing you out, not to make a point.  I always give the author a chance to explain themselves before downvoting, as I feel like an explanation can sometimes make a difference.  Cheers to you, as well.

Comment: @drrcknlsn And, somehow, you believe that after all my explanation, my answer deserves a down-vote instead of a no-vote, or an up-vote? Nice try.

Comment: @drrcknlsn [**Apparently there are quite a lot of people who do not agree wtih your sentiments.**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225893/are-classes-with-only-a-single-method-a-problem)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
function round_thousands($number){
    if($number < 1000){
        return $number;
    } else {
        return number_format($number/1000, 1).'K';
    }
}
```

Comment: simple :) works great many thanks! Didn't think about doing it this way :)

Comment: I usually use `number_format()` instead of `round()` as it takes regional thousands separators into account. If you don't need this, you can just use `round()`.

Comment: You can even write it in one line with the ternary operator;)

Answer (score 1):

A more elaborate version that does K, M, and B

```
function format_num($num, $precision = 2) {
    if ($num >= 1000 && $num < 1000000) {
        $n_format = number_format($num/1000,$precision).'K';
    } else if ($num >= 1000000 && $num < 1000000000) {
        $n_format = number_format($num/1000000,$precision).'M';
    } else if ($num >= 1000000000) {
        $n_format=number_format($num/1000000000,$precision).'B';
    } else {
        $n_format = $num;
    }
    return $n_format;
}
```